# Do I have to implement published algorithms in the same manner as the original source?

Tags: research-process, computer-science, validation

If you want to optimize a technique used in a given publication, is it considered necessary to use the same programming language and data sets?

Comment: Please don't use chat speak in posting here. I've also removed the parts about k-means and movie data sets, since that's particular to your project and therefore off-topic here.

Comment: Not really I thought this is academic and asking about the rule of research...Thank you that looks much better

Comment: Well, that kind of obscures things, too, because now you have a question asking about references for k-means, and one asking about the need to use the same programming language. At any rate, the questions about clustering, etc., is probably better suited for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com), the SE site devoted to statistical analysis.

Comment: Necessary for what ends, or as imposed by which set of rules?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use the same programming language, but it would be wise to use the same data sets (if available), to check that you get the same results and to compare performance.  Of course, you may want to use additional data sets.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the goal of your work.

If you want to use the algorithm for something else and just as one piece of the puzzle, you are free to implement it however you want. Especially with popular algorithms you will find that mostly only the very basic idea survives. The algorithm itself changes a lot over time with different improvements of various researchers.

If the algorithm itself is the core of your research, you should definitely keep all the same language and data sets to make your results comparable. If you then for example want to try it out in a different language, you should compare it to the original implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that "optimize" means "improve upon" (otherwise the entire question is meaningless).

Then the question is, what do you want to prove? Is it that your algorithm is better? In this case you would be well advised to stick to the original programming language. If you do not, it will be hard to counter the criticism that your performance improvements are due not to your own hard work, but simply to different efficiencies of the programming languages and/or compilers.

Sometimes the goal of the experiments is, in fact, to show the superiority of one programming language over another, see, e.g., http://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/ijoc.2.2.152. In this case, of course you would be free to use a different programming language.

That you should use the same data set in either case goes without saying.

Comment: I don't quite get the point of your second paragraph: even when not changing the language, you could always claim that the new algorithm just happens to be better suited for the optimizations performed by the compiler.

Comment: @DCTLib. Sure, but how would you prove that? Besides, this would be a very narrow contribution. I doubt it could be published.

Comment: No, I meant the *reviewer* could claim that. Regardless of whether the new implementation is in a different language or not, the engineering part may have been performed in a better way, and so regardless of whether the new implementation is in the same language, the reviewer may doubt that the new algorithm is intrinsically better.

Comment: @DCTLib. Have a look at the reference I linked. I believe the author addressed that, although new language features have made the article dated if not obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear what is the meaning of the phrase "optimize a technique", thus, it is difficult to tell, especially since it is most likely *discipline-* and, even, *context-dependent*. However, regardless of the above, technique, by definition, is independent of programming language (at least, IMHO it should be), so my answer to that part is **No**.

In regard to data sets, the situation is also rather fuzzy, as that also depends on domain, context and, perhaps, other factors. Nevertheless, I would suggest considering using the same data set (so, my answer to that part is **Yes**), if possible, along with a rather standard approach of *splitting* it into two (*training* and *test*) or three (*training*, *validation* and *test* - so called "three-way data split") subsets (that is, of course, if you perform relevant data analysis).